# Making Masonry.js Responsive in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jquery-masonry

I have implemented Passy's directive from Github to get Masonry working with AngularJS, which works fine.

https://github.com/passy/angular-masonry

This is absolutely fine, until trying to parse the method described by Passy to add responsiveness to the grid.

```
<masonry options="{ transitionTransition: '0.4s' }">
</masonry>
```

What I want to add here is something like this:

```
<masonry options="{ 'gutter': 10, 'columnWidth': '.grid-sizer' }">
</masonry>
```

But this doesn't do anything... Has anyone had the same issue, or can point me in the direction of some examples/docs?

Comment: Does `.grid-sizer` have a `width` set?

Comment: I set that in the CSS. Doesn't seem to apply the class, or display anywhere in the source.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution ? Passy's repo is great but not responsive ...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's an easy way to turn Angular Mansory responsive, but I was having the same problem and I've found a responsive alternative to it.

It's called "Angular Grid" and it describes itself as "Pinterest like responsive masonry grid system for angular". It works along with bootstrap or any other CSS grid system.

Here's a link to their github repo: https://github.com/s-yadav/angulargrid.

And to their demo/documentation page: http://ignitersworld.com/lab/angulargrid/